# JVM shutdown sequence and transaction management?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, spring-boot-actuator

I was wondering about JVM Shutdown sequence. Is there a sequence to shutdown, or the program ends abruptly ?
To be more verbose, let's say there's a methodA() which has 500 lines of code.
Shutdown is initiated using the spring boot's shutdown actuator when 250th line is being executed.
What happens here ?
Does

1. JVM wait to complete the 500 lines of code and then proceed with shutdown, or
2. JVM proceeds with termination on the 250th line of code itself and program ends abruplty?

Thanks !

Comment: These are two questions. Do you care about the JVM shutdown or Spring?

Comment: Both actually. More from Spring perspective..

Answer (score 0):

1 is generally true, but it can be changed.

Spring doesn't use JVM mechanics to shutdown. It tell all beans that interested to stop. Usually beans gracefully stop treads they use, but nothing stopping you from creating bean that use `Thread.stop` to shutdown treads.